# Add more properties in spring security UI grails plugin

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I'm using `Grails 4.0.9` and `spring security core grails plugin 4.0.3` and `spring-security-ui:4.0.0.M1`, I want to add some properties while the user is registering such as `telephone number and age`, how I can do this while using the default `Spring security default UI`

Comment: Hi, late to the party a bit but mind sharing what you did to get this going? Did you have to extend just the SpringSecurityUiService or the whole DefaultRegistrationCodeStrategy?

Answer (score 4):

The plugin generates the default implementation for you. So you would need to update the default generated templates for the RegisterController and forms.

Please check the [customisation section](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/latest/index.html#customization) in the plugin documentation.

Comment: I added as stated in the documentation and it created an empty registration controller !! so I copied all the actions from the original one found in the plugin , also copied the `RegisterCommand` inside the `RegisterContoller`, but after pressing `create your account` I got this error `No signature of method: grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.DefaultRegistrationCodeStrategy.createUser() is applicable for argument types: (c.s.RegisterCommand) values: [c.s.RegisterCommand@3eabeea3]
Possible solutions: createUser(grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterCommand)`

Comment: Could you please share a sample application?

Comment: ,find anything wrong with the shared code ?

Comment: Yes, you are seeing the above error because you are calling `uiRegistrationCodeStrategy.createUser(registerCommand)` with a different `RegisterCommand` class. You need to update this implementation to custom.

Comment: As per your requirements, what you want is reuse the UI whereas everything else need to be custom or extend the existing classes. So, you may need to override the SpringSecurityUiService bean definition with a new bean which would add `createUser(MyRegisterCommand)`.

Comment: Hi, late to the party a bit but do I need to extend just the SpringSecurityUiService or the whole DefaultRegistrationCodeStrategy?